# I have a python cgi script, I want to store the status or exit code of every line in a text file?

Tags: python, subprocess

Suppose i have a script like this:

```
subprocess.getoutput("sudo date")
subprocess.getoutput("some ssh command")
```

Now when the script runs every line will generate a status code. I want to save all those status codes in a text file but i don't want to save it in a variable and then append it in a text file.
It is run by Apache web server: httpd.

Comment: Could you please add a question into your post, we do not understand what you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getstatusoutput` insted of `getoutput` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput)):

```
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls /bin/ls')
(0, '/bin/ls')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('cat /bin/junk')
(1, 'cat: /bin/junk: No such file or directory')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('/bin/junk')
(127, 'sh: /bin/junk: not found')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('/bin/kill $$')
(-15, '')
```